# looping through files to count XML elements and adding total

Tags: java, variables

I am looping through a large number of xml files and counting the number of elements inside each file. My output is listing the number of records in each file but I am not sure how to add them all together.

```
package mypackage;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;



public class search {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // Creates array of file names

        String inputFile[];
        String directory ="FILE DIRECTORY";

        inputFile = new String[] {



                file1,file2,file3,blah,blah,blah



        };



        try {

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in), 8 * 1024);


            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

            // Get input element from user
            System.out.print("element name: ");
            String element = reader.readLine();
            int total = 0;
            int subTotal = 0;

            for(int i=0;i<=294;i++){

                Document doc = factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(inputFile[i]);

                NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName(element);
                subTotal = nodes.getLength();
                total =+ nodes.getLength();

                System.out.println(inputFile[i] +" # of " + element +  " elements " +  subTotal );
            }

            System.out.println("Total # of " + element +  " elements " +  total );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Additional info for clarification.

I am currently getting this

```
file1 # of  elements 4
file2 # of  elements 5
file3 # of elements 6
```

I want this:

```
file1 # of  elements 4
file2 # of  elements 5
file3 # of elements 6
combined # of elements 16
```

Update to show results with Brunos code below:

```
file1 #   4
file2 # 5
file3 # 6
Total #  6
```

Comment: what's your question here? it seems like working code?

Comment: It does work I am asking how to total them together and write it to the console. Right now it lists each file individually which is fine but it doesn't total them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not pretty sure about what you really want. If you want to add the result of all elements in all files, just put your total variabel as a field of the class, or a external variable, and aways add it to the length of the new nodeList.

Something like that:

```
        int total = 0;
        int subTotal = 0;

        for(int i=0;i<=294;i++){

            Document doc = factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(inputFile[i]);

            NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName(element);
            subTotal = nodes.getLength();
            total += nodes.getLength();

            System.out.println(inputFile[i] +" # of " + element +  " elements " +  subTotal );
        }

        System.out.println("Total # of " + element +  " elements " +  total );
```

If it is not what you are looking for, please explain better and post the rest of your code.
It is untested code.

Comment: haha - too obviuos for me - i didn't realize he didn't have the count variable outside the loop, omg... *shameonme*

Comment: I edited my post for clarify on what I am trying to do.

Comment: Happens a lot with me too :p

Comment: @user2941841 Bruno has your solution, it just needs a final System.out.println(Total # of elements "+total );

Comment: This still doesnt total them it gives the same results twice instead of adding them. If i put the it outside of my code block it just gives me the total from the last file. Total keeps getting over written.

Comment: I edited, see if it is up to you @user2941841. Altought it is untested code.

Comment: have you put the final syso outside of the bracket as seen in brunos code? @user2941841

Comment: It can't be, have a look on the line: total =+ nodes.getLength();

Comment: copied your code exactly and its still overriding total. It lists elements for each files then lists one more time the total number of elements but the number is not the actual total just the amount of elements in the last file it checks. updated original post to show results with code you provided.

Comment: Please, post your whole code, maybe it is inside of another for() statement.

Comment: O my God, that is really strange, because it needs to add and dont override it, did you try debbuging it and see what is happing in line total =+ nodes.getLength(); ?

Comment: Got it to work. The answer was to switch =+ with += thanks for the help

Comment: wow, my fault, sorry. I'm going to edit my post to the right form, so other people don't get a wrong example.